# What is the longest distance over which echolocation is effective?

Tags: waves, acoustics, gyroscopes, gps, oceanography

Some animals, most notably bats, use echolocation in order to navigate and detect the location and size of objects and prey.  This usually takes place over short distances.

What are the theoretical limitations to scaling up this system for long range navigation purposes?

Comment: Thee are several problems: if the repetition rate of the signal is faster than the turn around time there is a disambiguation issue (this effectively trades range for time-like granularity), volume of the return signal and quality of the returned signal. All are complicated at one level or another.

Comment: This also depends on the medium.  Simple low powered fish finders can go 1000's of feet.  The military has classified systems so powerful they burst the receptors in dolphins.  Subs carry towed arrays for high resolution sonar that go for miles and miles.  https://www.fas.org/man/dod-101/navy/docs/es310/SNR_PROP/snr_prop.htm

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for the Bioacoustics SE (https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/).